# Error: CentralTendencies.exe has stopped working, upon clicking Build & Run in codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

This code is to find the mean, median and mode for a given sequence of number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{   /*Inputs*/
int n;
int a[n];
/*Outputs*/
float mean;
int median;
int mode;

printf("Enter the size of array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
         printf("\nEnter the values of array: ");
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
/*arrange in ascending order */
int i=0;
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    if(a[i]>a[i+1])
    {
        int temp = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}
}
/*Mean of the series*/
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
        sum = sum + a[i];
    mean = sum/n;
}

/*Median of the series*/
```

I hope the syntax of typecasting here is right, right?

```
int m = floor((double)n/2);
if(n%2==0)
{
 median = (a[m]+a[m-1])/2;
}
else
{
 median = a[m];
}

/*Mode of the series*/
int count;
int b = 0;
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    for(int t=0; t<n; t++)  //Compare a[i] with all the elements of the array
    {if(a[i]==a[t])
        {
                count = 0;
                count++;
        }
     if(b<count)                //Update the new value of mode iff the frequency of one element is greater than that
        {                   // of its preceding element.
            mode = a[i];
        }
    }
}

printf("The value of mean: %f",mean);
printf("\nThe value of mean: %d",median);
printf("\nThe value of mean: %d",mode);
return 0;
}
```

There were no errors in the code.

I received the following message on the prompt after "CentralT...... working":
Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 47.686 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: You declare n without initializing it and then try using it as the size of an array. That might be one of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot resize an array.

This line

```
int n;
```

defines `n` and leaves its value as garbage, a random value, perhaps `0`.

Based on what ever `n` holds this line

```
int a[n];
```

defines `a` as array to have the number of element as per `n` *now* has.

Reading into `n` in this line

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

does *not* change the number over `a`'s elements.

To fix this, define `a` only after `n` has a well defined, valid value:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

To really make sure `n` had been set you want to test the outcome of `scanf()` like for example:

```
do {
   if (1 != scanf("%d, &n))
   {
     puts("Bad input or failure reading n!\n");
     continue;
   }
} while (0);
```